# update checkbox value from the form to database(seralized) using update query in single variable

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

My project is a simple form which stores the data retrieves,and allows to edit

**EDIT**   has option to edit form details and stores back .

I am using update query to do so

> I want to store all checkbox in `cardtype` .
>
> Database looks like `Trainee ID Card,Permanent ID Card`(seralized)
>
> I am not able to `UPDATE` the details using update can anyone let me know what do I need to do

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cardtype" value="Trainee ID Card"<?php if(in_array("Trainee ID Card",$card_type)) echo "checked";?> />Trainee ID Card
<input type="checkbox" name="cardtype" value="Permanent ID Card"<?php if(in_array("Permanent ID Card",$card_type))  echo "checked";?> />Permanent ID Card
<input type="checkbox" name="cardtype" value=" ID Card"<?php if(in_array("ID Card",$card_type))  echo "checked";?> /> ID Card
```

> My update Query

```
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$fileno=$_POST['fileno'];
$doa=$_POST['doa'];
$cardcolor = $_POST['cardcolor'];
$cardtype = implode(",",$_POST['cardtype']);
$query3="update sql_re_up set firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', 
fileno='$fileno', doa='$doa' , cardcolor='$cardcolor', cardtype='$cardtype' 
where Id='$Id'";

 mysqli_query($connect,$query3);
```

Edit:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cardtype[]" value="Trainee ID Card"<?php if(in_array("Trainee ID Card",$card_type)) echo "checked";?> />Trainee ID Card
```

> Above correction allows me to display the edited check box but I am not able to add edited data to database

`Trainee ID Card,Permanent ID Card,ID Card` has been checked then only one `Trainee ID Card` get update I want all of them stored in `cardtype` variable as series.

Comment: you didn't treat the checkboxes as arrays

Comment: there's also no mysql here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I feel very silly now.Thank u

Comment: I take it that you changed all `name="cardtype"` to `name="cardtype[]"` *right?* ;-)

Comment: so; what's the status here, as per my previous comment?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I  am not able to update to database ??

Comment: I spot one issue - missing space between check box value and php code that writes checked property. It should be - <input type="checkbox" name="cardtype[]" value="Trainee ID Card"  <?php if(in_array("Trainee ID Card",$card_type)) echo "checked";?> />Trainee ID Card - Same mistake in other checkboxes code , too.

Answer (score 1):

For all those want to know how I solved

`update query changes`

`$query3="update sql_re_up set firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', fileno='$fileno', doa='$doa' , cardcolor='$cardcolor', cardtype='". $cardtype ."' where Id='$Id'";`

- cardtype='$cardtype'      to   cardtype='". $cardtype ."'

Input tag for Id card changes

`<input type="checkbox" name="cardtype" value="ID Card"<?php if(in_array("ID Card",$card_type))  echo "checked";?>/> ID Card`

- value=" ID Card"      to         value="ID Card"